# SQL Server CEIP login account

Tags: sql-server-2016, server

One of my servers have login of "DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$" in both login_name and original_login_name for SQLServerCEIP when checked using sp_who2.

Under services, SQL Server CEIP settings shows it is using "NT SERVICE\SQLTELEMETRY" logon.
(The service is also restarted just in case)

Anyone have any idea why is this happening?